# C11_Generic deduces true and false as integers

Tags: c, generics, c11

In C11 there is the `_Generic` macro that can allow for cool generic functions. However using `true` and `false` with this results in incorrect deduction in the normal case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define TypeName(x) \
  _Generic((x), \
    bool: "bool", \
    int: "int", \
    default: "unknown")

#if defined (__STDC_VERSION__) && (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L) && (__bool_true_false_are_defined)
# undef true
# define true ((bool)(1))
# undef false
# define false ((bool)(0))
#endif

int main(void)
{
    printf("1: %s\n", TypeName(1));
    printf("true: %s\n", TypeName(true));
    printf("false: %s\n", TypeName(false));
}
```

This prints:

```
1: int
true: bool
false: bool
```

However without the middle bit that redefines `true` and `false`:

```
1: int
true: int
false: int
```

Which means you cannot do `_Generic` functions such as:

```
struct Variant * const int32 = variant_create(1);
struct Variant * const boolean = variant_create(true);
```

**So my questions are**:

- Is the redefinition snippet a safe thing to do?
- Is this an oversight in the C11 standard or a bug in GCC and Clang?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both types are indeed macros:

> 7.18 Boolean type and values
>
> 3. The remaining three macros are suitable for use in #if preprocessing directives.
>     They are:
>      *true* which expands to the integer constant 1,
>      *false* which expands to the integer constant 0, 
>      and
>      *__bool_true_false_are_defined* which expands to the integer constant 1.

The last rule says you are allowed to redefine the macro:

> 4. Notwithstanding the provisions of 7.1.3, a program may undefine and perhaps then
>      redefine the macros bool, true, and false. <sup>259)</sup>
>
>    <sup>259) See ‘‘future library directions’’ (7.31.9)</sup>

in spite of the referenced rule :

> 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers
>
> 3. If the program removes (with #undef) any macro definition of an identifier in the first
>      group listed above, the behavior is undefined.

The rule *7.31.9* says redefining might not be a good idea:

> 7.31.9 Boolean type and values
>
> 1. The ability to undefine and perhaps then redefine the macros bool, true, and false is
>      an obsolescent feature.

So I suggest you create your own my_true and my_false macros which are cast to _Bool.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `true` and `false` in `stdbool.h` are just integers `1` and `0`, their types are indeed `int`, not `bool`.

> #### C11 §7.18 Boolean type and values `<stdbool.h>`
>
> The remaining three macros are suitable for use in `#if` preprocessing directives. They
>   are
>
> ```
> true
> ```
>
> which expands to the integer constant `1`,
>
> ```
> false
> ```
>
> which expands to the integer constant `0`, and
>
> ```
> __bool_true_false_are_defined
> ```
>
> which expands to the integer constant `1`.

Comment: This doesn't answer either of the questions I put forward. I *know* that the `true` and `false` are defined as integers. My example shows that this isn't ideal because type deduction fails for `_Generic`. The two questions are what I need answers for.

Comment: @MattClarkson I'm saying you get it as `int` because they are indeed `int`. The result isn't *incorrect* as you said in the question.

Comment: It's correct as defined by the compiler deduction rules but incorrect for my use case. You would expect `true` to deduce as a `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

C has no literals for integer types that are narrower than `int`, and, as others have said, the macros `false` and `true` are therefore defined as `0` and `1`, respectively. So the problem that you describe for `_Bool` is the same for all other narrow data types: it is difficult to trigger e.g a `short` variant in a type generic macro, and calling such a macro with `'A'` will not trigger a `char` variant either.

Your replacement macros are no good, since they are not usable in preprocessor `#if` expressions. If some code that you include afterwards uses them as such compilation will fail.

You could use

```
# define true ((_Bool)+1)
# define false ((_Bool)+0)
```

instead. The little plus `+` sign magically makes it that the preprocessor interprets them as `((0)+1)` and `((0)+0)` in expressions, and so they'd still do what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question "Is this an oversight in the C11 standard or a bug in GCC and Clang?" is "neither".

Others have explained why it's not a bug in GCC and Clang.

It's also not an oversight in the standard, which defines *true* and *false* that way for backwards compatibility.  If *true* were defined as *(bool)1* and *false* as *(bool)0*, it would be more likely to encounter incompatible definitions of the macros.  The most visible effect would be a warning.  Compilers in general do not warn if a redefinition of a macro (without intervening #undef) does not change the definition; hence, the simplest definition is the least likely to give problems in the wild.